# Unsetting Session by Reference does not work

Tags: php, session, reference, unset

I'm trying to unset Sessions with a function, so it is easier. 
I am calling the function like this: `unsetSession("index1/index2/index3/...)`

It works when I provide the full path to the last element. However, it doesnt work when I want to delete an element that holds further elements.

Example:

`$_SESSION`:

```
["test"]=>
array(1) {
  ["value1"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value2"]=>
    string(6) "String"
  }
}
```

This: `unsetSession("test/value1/value2")` will work and delete `value2`. 
This: `unsetSession("test/value1")` wont work. That is my problem.

Code:

```
PUBLIC function unsetSession($s) {

        if (!strstr($s, "/")) {

            unset($_SESSION[$s]);

        } 
        else {

            $temp = &$_SESSION;

            $path = explode('/', $s);

            if (!isset($temp[current($path)]) OR is_string($temp[current($path)])) return false;
            $temp = &$temp[current($path)];

            while ($next = next($path)) {

                if ((isset($temp[$next]) OR $temp[$next] == null) AND !is_array($temp[$next])) {

                    unset($temp[$next]);
                    return true;

                }

                $temp = &$temp[$next];

            }

            unset($temp); // <- DOES NOT UNSET SESSION, why?
            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }
```

Any idea why that doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

I’d replace the use of current() and next() for the function end() that provides the last element of the array:

```
   function unsetSession($s) {
    if (!strstr($s, "/")) {
        unset($_SESSION[$s]);
    } else {
        $path = explode('/', $s)
        unset(end($path));
    }
    return false;
    }
```